# Error message from API when sending POST with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I try to send an API request with cy.request but there seems to be something wrong with the data format. My code looks as follows:

```
cy.request({
                    url: Cypress.env("RtmApiUrl") + "/test-plan/",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + Cypress.env('RtmApiToken'),
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        body: {
                            "projectKey": "QAIR",
                            "summary": "API Test Regression",
                            "description": "Full regression",
                            "parentTestKey": "F-QAIR-TP-8",
                            "priority": {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "Medium"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "id": 10005,
                                "name": "Backlog"
                            },
                            "includedTestCases": []
                        },
                    },
                });
```

And the console output from Cypress Test Runner:

```
    CypressError: `cy.request()` failed on:

https://rtm-api.hexygen.com/api/test-plan/

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 400: Bad Request

This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx` or `3xx`.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`

-----------------------------------------------------------

The request we sent was:

Method: POST
URL: https://rtm-api.hexygen.com/api/test-plan/
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Authorization": "Bearer <some Token>",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "body": {
    "projectKey": "QAIR",
    "summary": "API Test Regression",
    "description": "Full regression",
    "parentTestKey": "F-QAIR-TP-8",
    "priority": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Medium"
    },
    "status": {
      "id": 10005,
      "name": "Backlog"
    },
    "includedTestCases": []
  },
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "content-length": 0
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

The response we got was:

Status: 400 - Bad Request
Headers: {
  "server": "Cowboy",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "expires": "0",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "content-length": "69",
  "date": "Tue, 13 Jul 2021 07:32:36 GMT",
  "via": "1.1 vegur"
}
Body: {
  "errorMessages": [
    "No content to map to Object due to end of input"
  ]
}
```

I already tried the same combination of header and body with Postman and curl and it worked. Is there something I missed?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, I missed a bracket at the end of the headers block. So this was a real classic layer 8 issue...

```
    cy.request({
                    url: Cypress.env("RtmApiUrl") + "/test-plan/",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + Cypress.env('RtmApiToken'),
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: {
                        "projectKey": "QAIR",
                        "summary": "API Test Regression",
                        "description": "Full regression",
                        "parentTestKey": "F-QAIR-TP-8",
                        "priority": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "Medium"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "id": 10005,
                            "name": "Backlog"
                        },
                        "includedTestCases": []
                    },
                },
    });
```